# Template specialisation in one TU hidden by another TU

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a **class template** which can be **specialised** in order to change behaviour of a utility function for user defined types.

I have one translation unit which uses the utility function **with my type's specialisation available**. The specialisation is used.

In a separate translation unit, if I call the utility function without including the specialisation, it changes the behaviour of the other TU (**the specialisation is not used in *both* TUs**)

### Here is a complete example describing my issue:

**`check.h`:** *defines the class template which can be specialised for user defined types*

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Check
{
    static void type();
};

template<typename T>
void Check<T>::type()
{
    std::cout << "check fall-back\n";
}

template<typename T>
void check(T&&)
{
    Check<T>::type();
}
```

**`type.h`:** *definition of my user-defined type*

```
#pragma once

enum Foo
{
    FOO,
    BAR
};
```

**`type_check.h`:** *specialises `Check` for `Foo`*

```
#pragma once
#include "type.h"
#include "check.h"

template<>
struct Check<Foo>
{
    static void type()
    {
        std::cout << "check Foo\n";
    }
};
```

**`lib.h`:** *TU header file*

```
#pragma once

void lib();
```

**`lib.cpp`:** *TU source file - uses the specialisation from `type_check.h`*

```
#include "lib.h"
#include "type_check.h"

void lib()
{
    check(FOO);
}
```

**`main.cpp`:**

```
#include "check.h"
#include "type.h"
#include "lib.h"
#include "type_check.h" // uncomment this to make specialisation avail to all

int main()
{
    check(5);
    lib();
//  check(FOO); // uncomment this to change behaviour of lib()`
    return 0;
}
```

### Results:

Calling `lib()` without calling `check(FOO)` in `main` results in the following:

```
check fall-back
check Foo
```

Calling `lib()` and `check(FOO)` in `main` results in the following:

```
check fall-back
check fall-back <-- main changes behaviour of lib
check fall-back
```

Including `type_check.h` in `main.cpp`, and then calling `lib()` and `check(FOO)` in `main` results in the following:

```
check fall-back
check Foo
check Foo
```

### Question:

Why does calling `check(FOO)` in a separate TU when the `Check<Foo>` specialisation is not available remove it from the overload set in `lib.cpp`?

### Notes:

I can't just put the `Check<Foo>` specialisation in the same file as the definition of `Foo`, as `Foo` is actually a generated file (protobuf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a violation of the One Definition Rule.  The linker sees two function definitions for the same function and will pick one.  No diagnostic is required.

In this case, `void Check<Foo>::type` is defined once by the instantiation of the template definition from check.h used in lib.cpp, while the other definition is from type_check.h used in main.cpp.

Comment: You should mention *which* function has two definitions